# email switch based on radio button selection

Tags: php, html

Trying to post submission of orders to different emails depending on which radio button is selected; Order or Quote. Once radio button is clicked the form should submit to the email that matches with the radio button choice.

Is there anyway way I can get any help with this? Any suggestions would be  greatly appreciated!

Thank you!!!

```js
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  //$phone = $_POST["sender_phone"];
  $message = $_POST["sender_message"];
  $radio = isset($_POST['cloudways_radio_field_Order']) ? $_POST['cloudways_radio_field_Order'] : $_POST['cloudways_radio_field_Quote'];
  switch ($radio) {
  case 'cloudways_radio_field_Order':
  $to = 'dummy.email@randomeaddress.com';
      break;
  case 'cloudways_radio_field_Quote':
  $to = 'dummy.email@gmail.com';
      break;
  }

  if (isset($_POST['cloudways_radio_field_Order'])) {
     $to = 'dummy.email@randomeaddress.com';
  }
  elseif (isset($_POST['cloudways_radio_field_Quote'])) {
     $to = 'dummy.email@gmail.com';
  }
  else {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";
  }
?>
```

```html
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="https://nashinternal.com/checkout-2/" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
  <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="Quote" name="cloudways_radio_field" id="cloudways_radio_field_Quote">
    <label for="cloudways_radio_field_Quote" class="radio ">Quote</label>
    <input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="Order" name="cloudways_radio_field" id="cloudways_radio_field_Order">
    <label for="cloudways_radio_field_Order" class="radio ">Order</label>
   </span>
  <div class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-wrapper">
    <div class="woocommerce-privacy-policy-text">
      <button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Request A Quote" data-value="Request A Quote">Request A Quote</button>
      <input type="hidden" id="woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce" name="woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce" value="f7ab4b6ee6">
      <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/?wc-ajax=update_order_review">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You might want to remove the emails/put dummy emails in

Answer (score 0):

You can use an associative array to make it simpler. E.g.:

```
$emails = [
'Quote' => 'aaa@example.com',
'Order' => 'bbb@example.com'
];

// ...
$to = $emails[$_POST['radio']];
// ...
```